# Trying to change the position of a div when clicked using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I'm editing a website for use on tablet, but obviously none of my :hover pseudo-classes will work.

I want to move a div up to reveal text by the same amount as when I hover, but I want it to happen when I click "up_down_icon.png".

Here is my html:

```
<div class="home_1">
    <div class="h_1_text_box">
        <h3>Our Concept</h3>
        <img class="icon" src="up_down_icon.png">
        <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.h_1_text_box {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
padding: 12px 16px 24px 16px;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Franklin Gothic;
position: relative;
top: 255px;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.h_1_text_box:hover {
position: relative;
top: 171px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.icon {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
position: absolute;
top: 11px;
left: 560px;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.h_1_text_box:hover > .icon {
transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Literally all I need to know is how to apply a change of position to .h_1_text_box, to be specific, moving it up 84px.

The answer is probably going to be really simple and I feel a little silly for asking, but my code is a bit long for me to get my head around applying JS. I haven't been able to find anything specific enough to help me out. If I have to change the order of anything in my HTML I don't mind.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add your code to fiddle, so that we can get an idea

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wk16qju9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an event listener to your icon which will listen for click events.
Then you would just need to add a css class to the parent element. You already have everything you need in your css defined.

Here is an example.

```js
var upDownIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('icon').item(0);

upDownIcon.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('move_up_down');
}, false)
```

```css
.h_1_text_box {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 12px 16px 24px 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Franklin Gothic;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.h_1_text_box.move_up_down {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

/*
.h_1_text_box:hover {
position: relative;
top: 171px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
*/

.icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 560px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;

  /* this is just for the span*/
  font-size: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.h_1_text_box.move_up_down > .icon {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

/*
.h_1_text_box:hover > .icon {
transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="home_1">
  <div class="h_1_text_box">
    <h3>Our Concept</h3>
    <span class="icon">&#8645;</span>
    <!--<img class="icon" src="up_down_icon.png">-->
    <p>Text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, works perfectly. Could I be a bother and ask a couple of questions to get my head around it?

What is the purpose of .item(0); ?
What does "false" do?
Can the function be called anything? As in, to be specific to the event (e.g., textBoxGrow)?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` which is an array like object. The `item(0)` method will get the first element from the `HTMLCollection`. Here is some more information on that https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName. You may also want to check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener. I have used an anonymous function in the event listener, but you can pass a named function as well. Just define `function textBoxGrow (event) {...` and pass it to `...addEventListener('click', textBoxGrow, false)`

Answer (score 0):

you can set top and left according to your requirement using simple JS -

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left = "100px";
document.getElementById("myBtn").style.top = "100px";
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is one of thousand ways ways you can do this using **JS**:

```js
function toogleClass() {
    var divhasClass = document.getElementById("onlyTouchDevices").classList;
    if (divhasClass.contains("showMore")) {
      divhasClass.remove("showMore");
    } else {
      divhasClass.add("showMore");
    }
  }
```

```css
.home_1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px 0px 96px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightblue;
  background-size: 600px 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.h_1_text_box {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 12px 16px 24px 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Franklin Gothic;
  position: relative;
  top: 255px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.showMore {
  position: relative;
  top: 171px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 560px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.h_1_text_box:hover > .icon {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
h3 {
  margin: 0 0 18 0;
  font-weight: lighter;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-after: 18px;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_1">
  <div class="h_1_text_box" id="onlyTouchDevices">
    <h3>Our Concept</h3>
    <img class="icon" src="up_down_icon.png" onclick="toogleClass()" />
    <p>Text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I have done here is just toggled the class that added/reset the `top` spacing which you have used when you hover that element.

Answer (score 0):

> may be this will help you, run my code snippet and check it out

```js
$('.icon').click(function(){
 $('.h_1_text_box').css('position','relative');
  $('.h_1_text_box').css('top','171px');
  $('.h_1_text_box').css('background-color','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)');
})
```

```css
.home_1 {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px 0px 96px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightblue;
    background-size: 600px 300px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.h_1_text_box {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
padding: 12px 16px 24px 16px;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Franklin Gothic;
position: relative;
top: 255px;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}



.icon {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
position: absolute;
top: 11px;
left: 560px;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.h_1_text_box:hover > .icon {
transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

h3 {
 margin: 0 0 18 0;
 font-weight: lighter;
 -webkit-margin-before: 0px;
 -webkit-margin-after: 18px;
 -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
 -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home_1">
    <div class="h_1_text_box">
        <h3>Our Concept</h3>
        <img class="icon" src="up_down_icon.png">
        <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```